# How to use figure attribute of mlab.surface in mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am trying to use `mayavi.mlab.surf()` to create a 3D surface
The Mayavi documentation mentions the followng syntax of `mayavi.mlab.surf()` function.

[image]

I am trying to use the `figure` field as follows:

`surf_3D = mlab.surf(data, figure="test.png", warp_scale=0.5 )`

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\supriya\CODES_ALL\Anaconda_3D_Codes\3D_Mayavi_Interactive_Plot_OKERDAM.py", line 672, in <module>
    app = Window(root)
  File "D:\supriya\CODES_ALL\Anaconda_3D_Codes\3D_Mayavi_Interactive_Plot_OKERDAM.py", line 266, in __init__
    surf = mlab.surf(data, figure="test2.png", warp_scale=0.5 )
  File "C:\Users\ysrao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 38, in the_function
    return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ysrao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 75, in __call__
    assert isinstance(figure, Scene) or figure is None
AssertionError
```

Can someone please help me as to *How to use this **figure** attribute from `mayavi.mlab.surf()` function.* I tried searching for examples, but to no avail. Nobody seems to have used this in their codes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the intension is to save the plot as an image use mlab.savefig
The figure parameter in surf is the figure object on which the surface has to be plotted.